# JDesktopPane boundary - JInternalFrame's not filling up entire desktop

Tags: java, swing, jinternalframe, jdesktoppane

I'd like to have my `JDesktopPane` be such that `JInternalFrames` that are inside of it can be maximized and fully block out the blue background (well, blue on a Mac at least) of the `JDesktopPane`. If you run this demo, you'll see that if you maximize the `JInternalFrame`, it does not take up the entire `JDesktopPane`. **How can I get the `JDesktopPane` set up so that the `JInternalFrame` does take up the entire JDesktopPane**?

In this image, I have ran the code below and have pressed the maximize button on the JInternalFrame, yet there is still "blue" showing on the JDesktopPane.

[image]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import javax.swing.JDesktopPane;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JInternalFrame;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;

/**
 *
 * @author Robert
 */
public class Temp {

    Temp() {
        boolean resizable = true;
boolean closeable = true;
boolean maximizable  = true;
boolean iconifiable = true;
String title = "Frame Title";
JInternalFrame iframe = new JInternalFrame(title, resizable, closeable, maximizable, iconifiable);

// Set an initial size
int width = 200;
int height = 50;
iframe.setSize(width, height);

// By default, internal frames are not visible; make it visible
iframe.setVisible(true);

// Add components to internal frame...
iframe.getContentPane().add(new JTextArea());

// Add internal frame to desktop
JDesktopPane desktop = new JDesktopPane();
desktop.add(iframe);

// Display the desktop in a top-level frame
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
frame.getContentPane().add(desktop, BorderLayout.CENTER);
frame.setSize(300, 300);
frame.setVisible(true);
    }
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        new Temp();
    }
}
```

Comment: Not infront on my mac at the mo, but do you mean you want to get ride of the frame??  Can you post a screen shot?

Comment: grr, tried to upload an image but it wouldn't work. basically, if you maximize the JInternalFrame inside the JDesktop, there is still blue that you can see (you can still see the desktop)...the JInternalFrame does not actually fill up the entire JDesktop. I'm trying to get it so that it DOES fill up the entire JDesktop

Comment: Ahh, so you want it so that the "frame" is removed.  This is "none" trival problem, as you need to take into account the frames menu bar.  I'll have a play around with some ideas and see what I come up with...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's amazing what you can find on google.  I've not checked this out myself, but this might help

[Disabling the shadow around JInternalFrames with the Aqua Look and Feel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7838084/disabling-the-shadow-around-jinternalframes-with-the-aqua-look-and-feel)

Comment: that problem does not relate to this question, unfortunately.

Comment: Really? From what i can tell, The reason the internal frame isn't filling the desktop area is because it's taking into account the shadow insets around the frame

Comment: @CodeGuy: The client property works for me in this [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8199839/230513); +1;

Answer (score 1):

You can override the `maximizeFrame()` method of the `DesktopManager` used by your `JDesktopPane`. There's a related example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6916503/230513).

Answer (score 0):

Tyr this

```
// Add internal frame to desktop
JDesktopPane desktop = new JDesktopPane();
desktop.add(iframe);
iframe.setMaximum(true);
```